# Method [validateNumberic] does not exist

Tags: javascript, laravel

My Controller is-

```
public function handleHome(Request $request) {
  $input = $request - > all();
  $validator = Validator::make($input, [
    'a' => 'required|max:255',
    'b' => 'required|numberic',
    'c' => 'required',
  ], [
    'required' => 'Bat buoc phai nhap',
    'numberic' => 'Can nhap so',
  ]);
  if ($validator - > fails()) {
    return redirect('home') -
      >
      withErrors($validator) -
      >
      withInput();
  } else {
    return redirect('home') - > with('message', 'everthing is good');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `numberic` to `numeric`:

```
'b' => 'required|numeric',
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-numeric